# pass dynamic loop value into json as different values to show in header of table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I have to pass my header from json array value.

```
const tableHeaders = [{children: headervalue}]
```

use it in Table component like

```
<Table headers={tableHeaders} />
```

Now I have a condition, in place of **headerValue** I need to pass the return value of this below condition

```
(!!usersToShow.length && (
        <div>
          <Checkbox
            aria-label={tr('Select All Users')}
            checked={this.state.isCheckedAll}
            onChange={e => {
              this._toggleAllCheckboxes(e);
            }}
            label={tr('Select All Users')}
          />
          {!!customHeaders.length &&
            customHeaders.map((header, index) => {
              return (
                <label key={`custom-header-${index}`}>
                  {header} //get header values
                </label>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      ))
```

If I directly use this condition in children, I get all the values in one tableheader(th) with 1 checkbox in the header.

How to get the value of {Header} for different different th or each value of header as each column header?
Please help.

Comment: do you want to return the whole second section of the code that you have posted? If yes, then wrap in in a component and pass the newly created component to `headers`

Comment: If I pass like that, in one th only all the values are coming. I need each value of {header} in each th